# How To wait a progress bar to finish it's process and then Verify the result?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I got a process, for example I create a Distribution group. This will execute a progress bar that should complete the task. There are 3 possible statuses. Failed, on progress, and Completed. How do I create a wait to wait the completion of the progress bar task. And then, check the result?

I want to use a explicit wait for this, but how to wait the status of this element?

Examples of Status External HTML.

- Completed status

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar ng-scope progress-bar-success" ng-if="t.percentage == '100'" style="min-width: 30px; height: 5px; width: 100%;" ng-class="{'progress-bar-danger' : t.percentage == '100' &amp;&amp; t.state == 'Failed','progress-bar-success' : t.percentage == '100' &amp;&amp; t.state != 'Failed'}" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{'width': '100%'}">                                                   </div>
```

- In progress:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active ng-scope" ng-if="t.percentage < '100'" style="min-width: 30px; height: 5px; width: 100%;" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{'width': '100%'}"> </div>
```

- Failed:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar ng-scope progress-bar-danger" ng-if="t.percentage == '100'" style="min-width: 30px; height: 5px; width: 100%;" ng-class="{'progress-bar-danger' : t.percentage == '100' &amp;&amp; t.state == 'Failed','progress-bar-success' : t.percentage == '100' &amp;&amp; t.state != 'Failed'}" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{'width': '100%'}"> </div>
```

How do I create a Explicit wait to wait until the status of the progress is finished, and then check if it was succesful or not? The only idea I have is to wait the class name to change the name from "*progress-bar-striped active*" to "*progress-bar-success*" or "*progress-bar-danger*" as is the only visible difference I see

[image]

Visualisation of the progress bars:

Comment: Please avoid asking question before you have tried everything you know.
That way you can ask the question in more clear way with all the findings. It helps both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this progress bar is a single object, which just change a set of attributes over time, u can do this:

Put it into a variable

```
IWebElement progressbar = 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class,'progress-bar'][0]");
```

Make a function to check it's attributes over time

```
public static void WaitForSuccess(this IWebElement _progressbar)
{
    for(int second = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        if(_progressbar.GetAttribute("class").Contains("progress-bar-success"))
        return;
        else if(_progressbar.GetAttribute("class").Contains("progress-bar-danger"))
        Assert.Fail("No success");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
Assert.Fail("Timeout");
}
```

If progress bars are different objects, you need a function which will search what you need over time

```
public static void WaitForSuccess()
{
    for(int second = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        if(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class,'progress-bar-success']") != null)
    return;
        else if(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class,'progress-bar-danger']") != null)
    Assert.Fail("No success");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
Assert.Fail("Timeout");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SeleniumConfiguration.WAIT_LIMIT));

waitForElement.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div[class*='progress-bar-success']")));;
```

You basically want to wait until the class of the element changes to the "success" status, therefore waiting for the class to appear should be sufficient

If you want to avoid ExpectedConditions as they are marked as obsolete, you can use the functions from [this site](https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras/blob/master/src/WaitHelpers/ExpectedConditions.cs)

EDIT: You have updated the question before I managed to finish the answer. What other wait apart from this one would you like to have? :) Or why do you want sth different?

Comment: Thanks for the help, the information is really usefull in that site. I was thinking more like a scenario like this. Check status of the bar, If status is in progress then wait until status is "Finished" or "Success", then assert if = to success and pass the testcase, if it failed =  testcase failed

Comment: I recommend making your own package with expected conditions so that you can maintain it yourself. Honestly though it rarely changes, and may only need new items added or updated with selenium 4.x coming out.

Comment: @bsullit You can use the **GetAttribute("class")** and then check, whether it contains the specific class part, however just using the Wait basically does the same thing, without the if/switch block. The only difference is that if it fails to load in time, it'll throw an exception and fail the test case in this way and not via Assert.
If you really wanted to use the Assert part, you could do the Try/Catch block, catch the **NoSuchElementException** inside the catch and throw an Assert.Fail